# Как использовать регистратор нажатия клавиш (keylogger) внутри программы (игры "Змейка")?

Tags: python, python-3.x, логирование, клавиатура

Всем привет! Возникла необходимость сделать так, чтоб при управлении Змейкой происходила регистрация нажатий стрелок управления персонажем и запись их в логах. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно внедрить класс, в котором описывается keylogger в основной модуль Main? При различных попытках внедрения у меня либо запускается отдельно "Змейка", либо отдельно keylogger (и все это при старте одного и того же  main).

Вот код Main:

```
import pygame
from control import Control
from snake import Snake
from gui import Gui
from food import Food


pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((441, 441))
pygame.display.set_caption("Snake")
control = Control()
snake = Snake()
gui = Gui()
food = Food()
gui.init_field()
food.get_food_position(gui)
var_speed = 0


while control.flag_game:
    control.control()
    window.fill(pygame.Color("Black"))
    snake.draw_snake(window)
    food.draw_food(window)
    gui.draw_level(window)


    if var_speed % 80 == 0 and control.flag_pause:
        snake.move(control)
        snake.check_barrier(gui)
        snake.eat(food, gui)
        snake.check_end_window()
        snake.animation()
    var_speed += 1
    pygame.display.flip()
```

А вот код keylogger-а:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Listener


class Key:

    def write_to_file(key):
        letter = str(key)
        print(letter)
        letter = letter.replace("'", "")
        with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
            f.write(letter + '\n')

    with Listener(on_press=write_to_file) as l:
        l.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью многопоточности. Подключите библиотеку threading и запустите keylogger в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow на Русском! Если не сложно -- постарайтесь оставлять более подробные ответы. Пока выглядит не очень понятно. Возможно, стоит добавить конкретный код для наглядности.